# Raspberry Pi and SPI interface (Python): how to transfer data?

Tags: python, c, raspberry-pi

I'm using the SPI interface on my Raspberry Pi.

I can read the registers of the chip (first 20 registers) attached to SPI0 with the following code:

```
spi=spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)

x=spi.readbytes(20)

k=0
for i in x:
        print(k,hex(i),i)
        k=k+1
```

My question is: how do I set the value of a specific register using "spi.xfer"? I have no idea what parameters the xfer(...) function takes.

How do I read a value from a specific register using "spi.xfer"?

Although I do have the original C code; I still cannot decipher how to use xfer(...).

Here is the C code:

https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev/blob/master/spidev_module.c

Answer (score 1):

I believe this line of code is key:

```
PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O|IHB:xfer", &list, &speed_hz,
                 &delay_usecs, &bits_per_word)
```

[The documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.2p2/ext/parseTuple.html) tells us that the formatting string means:

- `O` - a Python object
- `|` - indicates that the following are optional
- `I` - an `int`
- `H` - a `short`
- `B` - a `char`
- `:` - start of function name string (`xfer`)

Of these, it seems sensible to assume that the `list` is the data to send, and indeed it seems to be interpreted as a list of bytes to send.

Since SPI tends to send and receive in parallel, futher reading of the code leads me to believe that each value in `list` will be replaced by the byte that was received when that particular byte was sent. It's weird, but that's SPI for you.